# Google analytics tracking dynamic data

Tags: google-analytics

First off, sorry if this is the wrong forum to ask this type of question. If it is, please feel free to put me straight.

Is there a way to track a single bit of dynamic data using google analytics. 
EG. I've got a used car website that dynamically pulls vehicle details. Although not part of the URL variables, one of those bits of information is the vehicle registration. Can I somehow include that in the analytics code so it's tracked on their stats.

Sorry if this is a quite broad question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is what event tracking is for: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: Spot on. This is just what I was looking for. Big thanks. I'll accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow allows me to. Thanks again.

Comment: i think [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#examples) should be more useful for your requirement.